# adding a device path in linux

Tags: linux, unix

I deleted the device path by running the command: `echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/delete` on Redhat Linux. Since it was the only path, I no longer have connectivity to that machine. I am able to `ping` it, not able to `ssh` to it.

How can I add the device path back? I found a [link](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Online_Storage_Reconfiguration_Guide/adding_storage-device-or-path.html) on how to add a new path. But I am not sure how to run those commands since I have no access to the machine. Do I have to physically reboot it?

Comment: in ssh what error you are getting?

Comment: @max ssh error: `Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: by running this command `echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/delete` you disconnected the disk. ya you have to physically reboot, i think your system got hang i think.

Comment: You'll need to reboot it. ICMP isn't really going to help you here, you need a shell.

Comment: just reboot the system this is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what this command did

I think it will disconnect the device means `sda`

I tried the same thing, and i also got the same error

> [max@localhost ~]$ ssh test@10.10.2.12
>
> **Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer**

It means the connection was forcibly closed by a remote host due to some reason.

After that I rebooted the system, now it's working fine.

**I have no access to the machine** for this i don't have any solution.

Comment: yea, I was almost sure that I had to reboot the system as I can't do run else to fix if I can't `ssh` to it. Just wanted to know if anyone has any other idea. Thanks for reproducing it on your machine.

Comment: @KingsIndian I learned a new thing today because of you... thanks